# Why use Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I was using Eclipse and migrated over to Android Studio before sometime. I was introduced to Gradle for the first time. I have read that it is build automation for building, testing and publishing. But I have done these tasks one at a time while developing apps. I will code then test if it is working and then when I am happy with the result and think it is good enough to be used by everyone, I will publish it. Where does gradle come in between all these? Sorry if it is a very noob question but I have been reading and I am still unable to get my head around all this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first there are some ideological reasons. Some developers just love command line tools. And you can dramatically increase your speed by chosing command line over GUI.

At the moment you are fine with your build process. But the grade of Automation is just limited, when using a gui tool. It will be made just for some special cases. With something like gradle, which just uses an entire scripting language for builds, there are no limits at all. And this is the second reason.

How you would achive automatically build the project, push apk on 50 different mobile devices, run the testsuite and then deploy the app to play and amazon after successfull test run every time when code is merged from develop to master branch with eclipse only?

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in such simple terms. That really helped.

Answer (score 8):

The main advantage of the new Gradle-based build system is, you can easily define multiple

- Build Types (E.g. debug and release)
- Product Flavours (E.g. lite and pro version)

And define the whole build process for each one of those (and combinations) individually, such as:

- Code set
- Debuggable
- Application Id
- Signing Config
- Dependencies

This allows for very neat things like having a different application id (package name) for debug releases, so that both release and debug can be installed at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed in the same time"?

Comment: You can't install two apps with the same package name (ID) on the same device at the same time.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Both of them can now be installed side-by-side on the same device.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a dependency management tool like maven or gradle for a good size project.
Also, it will help you automate the release process which could be very complex

For a small personal app, it maybe overkill.